# Collection View Firebase Not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am going to make a app like a public photo gallery. There is no error but it can't upload photos to `Firebase Storage` I have login system too.

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MobileCoreServices

class publicAlbumViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var value = 1
    var imageArray:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "second")!]
    var metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let albumRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("albumNum")
        albumRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            print(snap.value as! Int)
            self.value = snap.value as! Int
        }
        let albumImageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("albumNum")
        for num in 1...value {
            albumImageRef.child("\(num)").dataWithMaxSize(Int64.max, completion: {(data, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.imageArray.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return value
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("publicAlbumCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlbumCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let albumImageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("albumNum")

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        let newImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 3.0)
        self.metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        albumImageRef.child("\(value + 1)").putData(newImage!, metadata: self.metadata){metadata, error in
            if error == nil {}

        }
    }

    @IBAction func plusButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: There are several issues here: 1) the call to set `self.value` is asynchronous, meaning that your for loop may be iterating over 1 to 0, and you won't actually download anything. You'll want to do something else to get the necessary files. 2) you never reload the collectionview (`self.collectionView.reloadData()`), so even if you get a photo and add it to the array, you'll notice that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't fire because you never trigger it.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE and checking out the associated code https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd to get an idea of how to use Firebase Storage and Realtime Database on iOS :)